# Passing parameters to multiple tasks from Airflow UI

Tags: airflow

I have an airflow DAG with 50 tasks. In order to pass the date parameter to all 50 tasks what can be short way from airflow ui.

The parameter format for one taks is:

```
  {
  "task_name_1": {
      "path": "./data-code-path/dw/python_repo",
      "script": "python_script.py",
      "params": "--group_id \"TABLE_NAME_144115261091381252\" -w \"WAREHOUSE_NAME\" -s \"2024-01-06\" -e \"2024-01-07 00:59:59.999000\" "
    }
  }
```

If I follow current approach (which works) I will have to pass params to all 50 tasks as below:

```
{
  "task_name_1": {
      "path": "./data-code-path/dw/python_repo",
      "script": "python_script.py",
      "params": "--source_id \"TABLE_NAME_1\" -w \"WAREHOUSE_NAME\" -s \"2024-01-06\" -e \"2024-01-07 00:59:59.999000\" "
    }
  "task_name_2": {
      "path": "./data-code-path/dw/python_repo",
      "script": "python_script.py",
      "params": "--source_id \"TABLE_NAME_2\" -w \"WAREHOUSE_NAME\" -s \"2024-01-06\" -e \"2024-01-07 00:59:59.999000\" "
    } ......
      ......
      ......
  "task_name_50": {
      "path": "./data-code-path/dw/python_repo",
      "script": "python_script.py",
      "params": "--source_id \"TABLE_NAME_50\" -w \"WAREHOUSE_NAME\" -s \"2024-01-06\" -e \"2024-01-07 00:59:59.999000\" "
    }
  }
```

What I am looking for is an easy way to pass date params that gets passed to each task.
I tried below json params but it does not get passed to any of the tasks.

```
  {
      {"params": "-s \"2024-01-01\" -e \"2024-01-05 00:59:59.999000\" "}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following options?

**Using Variables**, here is a good source to walk through setting and getting them during task execution. [source](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-variables#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20Airflow%20UI%E2%80%8B,Import%20Variables%20from%20a%20file.)

**DAG Factory** you can pass params into dags via one Factory. [source](https://medium.com/data-engineering-indonesia/how-to-build-your-own-apache-airflow-dag-factory-8ad895423881)

**XCOM** you can set data into XCOMs and get them during task execution [official](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html)